# Excel VBA : Add hidden information/property to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a very simple code to move a bunch of cells one block to the left or to the right using buttons. The problem is that I don't want the user to be able to move a cell twice in the same direction. For this i need to add a hidden property to the cell that can be used to check if it was already moved from its initial position and save this info when the file is closed and reopened.

This way, before moving, for exemple a cell to the left, i can check this property and find out whether it was already moved to the left once before or not and display an error message in this case.

It would be enough if I can set this property to be equal to -1, 0 or +1 depending on whether it was moved to the left, centered, or moved right. I know i can use the comment property but i would prefer to use a hidden property for this.

Is there a clean way to do this ? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the code the performs the move?

Comment: I can see moving cells left or right, but what does "centering" look like?

Comment: ActiveCell.MergeArea.Cut  ... ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate ... ActiveSheet.Paste ... I'm using MergeArea because the cell i'm moving is merged

Comment: @TimWilliams by centered i meant "in it's initial postion" .. position 0 .. not moved or returned to its starting position.

Comment: I didn't use the [new cell position]*.Value = [original cell]*.Value then use [old cell].ClearContents because i wanted the formatting of the cell to move with it too.

Comment: @WhiteHat writes to ID don't survive close/open of the workbook (tested in Excel 2010)

Comment: what about using cells on a `VeryHidden` sheet to store the property value...?

Comment: What's the scope of the tracking? Single worksheet, multiple sheets? Within a fixed range or free-form range?  Can cells being tracked be overwritten by other moved cells?

Comment: You could make the last character white, or your background color, and change it to -,0,+ depending on what is wanted.  Then all you have to do is read the right most character to make your decision.

Comment: @WhiteHat  I have dozens of sheets, that's the problem .. i don't want to double the number of sheets even if they're 'Veryhidden'. I think there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @TimWilliams There's 15+ sheets with 10 main rows in each ( what i mean by a main row is a group of multiple rows ). In each main row there's these filled cells that take 3 vertical cells forming a one main cell. There's multiple main cells (that i want to move) in a main row, and there's a horizontal gap of empty cells between two main cells so if i move a cell one block to the left/right there's no risk of overwriting. To move the cells i ask the user to select the middle one between the 3 vertical cells and click on left/right buttons to move all three, but i'm only tracking the middle one.

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah that's a way to do it but not a clean way. Maybe the same could be done using comments

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an available (and preferably unused) cell property where I could store a value for this cell, and then reference it later.  The "ID" property seems ideal.  It is a String variable that only gets used if you save the workbook to a web page, and want to reference this cell using HTML.  Otherwise, this property is not utilized.

This is a link to the explanation of the property:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.id

For example, the following code sets a value in the ID property:
ActiveCell.ID = "123456789"

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be to create hidden `Name`s on the sheet, using a defined naming convention, to store the move status value.

Logic flow would be:

- On an attempt to move a cell, check if a name exists for that cell
- if not, then cell has not previously been moved, so permit move
- if yes, get value of name to check if move is permitted.

.

- If a move is executed:
- if name alerady exists, update its value
- if not, create and set value

Sample code fragments:

```
Sub SetHiddenName(r As Range, v As Long)
    Dim nm As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nm = r.Worksheet.Names("__" & r.Address(0, 0))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If nm Is Nothing Then
        Set nm = r.Worksheet.Names.Add(Name:="__" & r.Address(0, 0), _
        RefersTo:=v, _
        Visible:=False)
    Else
        nm.RefersTo = v
    End If
End Sub


Function GetValueOfName(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim nm As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set nm = r.Worksheet.Names("__" & r.Address(0, 0))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If nm Is Nothing Then
        ' Return required value for not previously set range
        GetValueOfName = ""
    else
        GetValueOfName = nm.RefersTo
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this today, although it seems to work with one cell, when i switch between sheets or move one cell then select another one and try to move it, this error message appears : 'Run-time error ''1004'': Application-defined or object-defined error.' .. Btw in your code, the information i wish to store is stored in the RefersTo and not the name so r is the cell i'm moving and v is the info, is that right ?

Comment: My answer is _not_ a complete solution, but rather an approach you can use to store hidden data.  You will need to build a solution around it.  Managing the Names, the names of the Names, and the data they store is left to you...