# When an Excel worksheet is copied, its CustomProperties collection does not get copied?

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started working with `Excel.CustomProperties`. To be clear, this is not  `Excel.CustomDocumentProperties`. I need to store certain worksheet-specific settings for use by various VBA macros, and `CustomProperties` is perfect for the task. Or so I thought.

Unfortunately, I found the `CustomProperties` collection gets left behind if the worksheet is copied. This happens whether the copy is done in the UI by the user, or in VBA with the `Worksheet.Copy` method.

Is this by design, or is it an oversight by Microsoft?

If by design, why?

Are there any tricks to make it work if the user copies the sheet in the UI?

Sample code below...

```
Public Sub CustomPropertyTest()
    
    'Run this is new blank workbook.
        
    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wss         As Excel.Sheets
    Dim ws1         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cps1        As Excel.CustomProperties
    Dim cp1         As Excel.CustomProperty
    Dim ws2         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim cps2        As Excel.CustomProperties
    Dim cp2Count    As Long
    Dim wsLast      As Long
    
    Set xl = Excel.Application
    Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    Set wss = wb.Worksheets
    
    Set ws1 = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set cps1 = ws1.CustomProperties
    Set cp1 = cps1.Add("cpTestName", "cpTestValue")
    'CustomProperty now exists in first worksheet.
    
    wsLast = wss.Count
    ws1.Copy After:=wss.Item(wsLast)
    'This can also be done in the UI by right-clicking on the worksheet tab
    'and choosing "Move or copy...".
    
    wsLast = wss.Count
    Set ws2 = wss.Item(wsLast)
    Set cps2 = ws2.CustomProperties
    cp2Count = cps2.Count
    
    ' cp2Count is = 0
    ' The CustomProperties collection was not copied.
    ' CustomProperties.Item(1) exists in first worksheet, but not the copied one.
    ' Why?

    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: While the subject of this Q is interesting,  your first two Q's are unanswerable except by MS insiders.  As to tricks to "make it work" I'd say use a different feature,  eg worksheet scoped [`Names`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.names) (possibly hidden or veryhidden)

Comment: I would suggest same as @chrisneilsen: add a worksheet name and set visibility to false

Comment: Ah...yes. A veryhidden worksheet might work. I'm aware of them but haven't had the need to use one yet. I wonder how truly hidden they are. I know they become invisible in the UI, but I wonder if other apps can see them. For instance, if the workbook is browsed for import in Microsoft Access, SQL Server, or SSIS, they show $filtersheets, whether currently active or not. When I want hidden, I want HIDDEN. That's why I tried to use `CustomProperties`. Thank you both for the suggestion. @Chris I'll give you credit if you want to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a hidden worksheet,  rather,  a hidden Name.  Follow the link in my comment to see what that is. I suggested that because  you seemed to want to attach hidden data to a specific sheet..

Comment: ... I suggested that because  you seemed to want to attach hidden data to a specific sheet. Including a hidden worksheet doesn't achieve that, so I'm now confused  on what you actually want to achieve.   Can you explain that?

Comment: @Chris, ahh yes I did jump ahead before really thinking it through. Some of the data does describe ranges, so `Names` could work for those, but there are other settings to store as well. I think I have a test plan forming in my head. I should create a worksheet with as many object collection types as I can attach to it, copy it to a new sheet, and then see what else gets left behind like `CustomProperties` did.

Comment: Fyi Names are not limited to Ranges.  They can also store any text data

Comment: Oh? How so? I see a `.Name` has a `.Comment` that might work, but I'm not sure how text could be stored in the `.RefersTo` value.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098588/445425)

Comment: [Also here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/definednames.aspx)